# Creating files using Notepad

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that reads values from an external file. I am creating the file using Notepad, but in putting in values do I need to separate the values by any symbol like a semicolon? Or is it sufficient to put the values on separate lines? I ask because my program is supposed to read in each value separately.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Or no.  Whatever your program expects, that's what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you read them in. If you are using some popular Java objects to read in the file, a new line would work just fine. You can also specify "delimiters" in Java (and other languages) so that you can stop when you reach the end of that value.

Best bet is to use "readLine" methods which look for a newline character and nothing else. That way your notepad file is a bit more readable for humans.

Comment: Ah, I see that you tagged C++, in that case the fstream object has a readline method as well

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ that is for the C++ object ifstream which can use the geline function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both, if the value are related all to the same attribute, i would use the line feed approach.
If the values are related to different attributes (e.g. name and age of persons), then i would separate both values with a comma, and make a linefeed for th enext person:

Example:

```
#name,age
John,23
Jimmy,28
```

or if the file contains only ages:

```
#age
23
28
```

If you are a nice  person, you should create a comment in the first line, which you overread